# raw materials into finished goods program in asp.net C#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a master table which show to make a finished good what are the raw materials needed and qty as follows

```
Finished    RawMaterial  Qty
A            x             2
A            Y             2
A            Z             1
```

ie, to produce A i need x(2),y(2) and z(1).

if a person asked he need materials to produce 10 As, then i need to issue x(20),y(20) and z(10). I can issue it using more than one issue slip.ie,in one issue slip they give x(10),y(20),z(10), in the next issue slip they issue x(10)(remaining items). i have to enter the finished product count in to GRN. GRn also multiple entries like if one day i receive 4 finished A Product, the next day 3 A like that. what i  want to know is how to design this. can you give any examples? it is like manufacturing concept

Comment: What do you think would be a design approach? (Ie. show some effort, don't just have us do your (home)work.)

Comment: sorry Mr Richard dont think like that. i just ask some ideas.